# How to retrieve records with duplicate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having problem retrieving the PLAYERs that has PLAYER_SCOREs that has duplicate PLAYER_SCORE. The criteria for PLAYER_SCORE to be considered duplicate it has other record that has the same P_ID, SCORE_1, SCORE_2, SCORE_3, and SCORE_4.

PLAYER TABLE:

```
+------+---------+
| P_ID | NAME    |
+------+---------+
|   12 | Juan    |
|   13 | Miguel  |
|   14 | Luna    |
|   15 | Placido |
+------+---------+
```

PLAYER SCORE TABLE

```
+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| PS_ID | P_ID | SCORE_1 | SCORE_2 | SCORE_3 | SCORE_4 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|     1 |    1 |      87 |      96 |      79 |      93 |
|     2 |    1 |      87 |      96 |      97 |      88 |
|     3 |    1 |      87 |      96 |      79 |      93 |
|     4 |    2 |      85 |      84 |      85 |      94 |
|     5 |    2 |      87 |      96 |      22 |      44 |
|     6 |    2 |      85 |      84 |      85 |      94 |
|     7 |    3 |      79 |      96 |      82 |      84 |
|     8 |    3 |      97 |      96 |      92 |      95 |
|     9 |    3 |      87 |      96 |      97 |      87 |
|    10 |    4 |      89 |      75 |      99 |      97 |
|    11 |    4 |      97 |      96 |      92 |      95 |
|    12 |    4 |      87 |      96 |      97 |      87 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My sql scripts:

Script 1 :

```
SELECT P.P_ID, NAME FROM PLAYER P 
INNER JOIN PLAYER_SCORE PS ON PS.P_ID = P.P_ID
GROUP BY P_ID, SCORE_1, SCORE_2, SCORE_3, SCORE_4
```

RESULT:

```
+------+---------+
| P_ID | NAME    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | Juan    |
|    1 | Juan    |
|    2 | Miguel  |
|    2 | Miguel  |
|    3 | Luna    |
|    3 | Luna    |
|    3 | Luna    |
|    4 | Placido |
|    4 | Placido |
|    4 | Placido |
+------+---------+
```

Script 2 :

```
SELECT P_ID, NAME FROM (
SELECT P.P_ID, NAME FROM PLAYER P
INNER JOIN PLAYER_SCORE PS ON PS.P_ID = P.P_ID
GROUP BY P_ID, SCORE_1, SCORE_2, SCORE_3, SCORE_4
) AS PLAYER GROUP BY P_ID
```

Result :

```
+------+---------+
| P_ID | NAME    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | Juan    |
|    2 | Miguel  |
|    3 | Luna    |
|    4 | Placido |
+------+---------+
```

Expected :

```
+------+--------+
| P_ID | NAME   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | Juan   |
|    2 | Miguel |
+------+--------+
```

Any help... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep only duplicates, so restrict output with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT P.P_ID, NAME FROM PLAYER P 
INNER JOIN PLAYER_SCORE PS ON PS.P_ID = P.P_ID
GROUP BY P_ID, NAME, SCORE_1, SCORE_2, SCORE_3, SCORE_4
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
SELECT P_ID, NAME FROM 
PLAYER INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT P_ID FROM PLAYER_SCORE 
  GROUP BY P_ID, SCORE_1, SCORE_2, SCORE_3, SCORE_4
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS SCORE ON SCORE.P_ID = PLAYER.P_ID
```